# How to Code Calendar from jsfiddle to local host

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can run my calendar code in jsfiddle, but it doesn't appear in local host. I think there's more code needed in html. This is on javascript. I hope someone can help. Thank you

```
#HTML
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id="dialog" title="" style="display:none;">Are you sure want to delete it?</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/49/ <-- original code

Comment: Are you including `fullcalendar.js`?

Comment: yes, I already include it.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not adding the needed libraries in your `<head>`.

If you head over to jsfiddle and checkout the left hand side of the page.
Those are the needed libraries you should import.
[Left Hand side menu](https://prnt.sc/pzhatb)

How does importing libraries work? See [w3s tutorial on adding librariers (example jquery)](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: May I know how to store the event on my localhost. Because whenever I refresh it, it disappears.